# Django raw() query with SIMILAR TO errors 'tuple' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am making a few queries and then removing duplicates based on rank for a cemetery burial app. I am trying to use PostgreSQL's SIMILAR TO in my last search rank, but any time I use it I get the 'tuple' object has no attribute 'id'.

Here are two queries:

```
query1 = """
            SELECT "burials_burial"."id", "burials_burial"."name_id",
                "burials_burial"."grave_id",
                "burials_burial"."interment_date",
                "burials_burial"."user_id",
                "cemeteries_grave"."search1_id" AS "cemetery_id",
                '2' AS "rank"
            FROM "burials_burial"
            INNER JOIN "names_name"
                ON ( "burials_burial"."name_id" = "names_name"."id" )
            INNER JOIN "cemeteries_grave"
                ON ( "burials_burial"."grave_id" =
                    "cemeteries_grave"."id")
            WHERE (
                (LOWER("names_name"."first_name") IN {0!s})
                OR (LOWER("names_name"."middle_name") IN {0!s})
                OR (LOWER("names_name"."last_name") IN {0!s})
            )
        """

query2 = """
            SELECT "burials_burial"."id", "burials_burial"."name_id",
                "burials_burial"."grave_id",
                "burials_burial"."interment_date",
                "burials_burial"."user_id",
                "cemeteries_grave"."search1_id" AS "cemetery_id",
                '1' AS "rank"
            FROM "burials_burial"
            INNER JOIN "names_name"
                ON ( "burials_burial"."name_id" = "names_name"."id" )
            INNER JOIN "cemeteries_grave"
                ON ( "burials_burial"."grave_id" =
                    "cemeteries_grave"."id")
            WHERE (
                (LOWER("names_name"."first_name") SIMILAR TO {0!s})
                OR (LOWER("names_name"."middle_name") SIMILAR TO {0!s})
                OR (LOWER("names_name"."last_name") SIMILAR TO {0!s})
            )
        """
```

When I call the queries I supply in the appropriate search parameters here:

```
names1 = Burial.objects.raw(query1.format(terms))
names2 = Burial.objects.raw(query2.format(terms.replace('\'', '').replace(', ', '|').replace('(', '\'%(').replace(')', ')%\'')))
```

Lastly, I just try to go through the names and do something with them:

```
for names in (names1, names2):
    for n in names:
        <do something here>
```

Now for where things are weird. For names1 I get my results and I can loop through them. For names2 I get the error noted above. Why?

I have looked at raw query output to make sure that what I supply to PostgreSQL is valid. Running the queries as output by the python shell gives me results as I expect:

```
IN: print names1.raw_query

OUT: SELECT "burials_burial"."id", "burials_burial"."name_id",
                        "burials_burial"."grave_id",
                        "burials_burial"."interment_date",
                        "burials_burial"."user_id",
                        "cemeteries_grave"."search1_id" AS "cemetery_id",
                        '25' AS "rank"
                    FROM "burials_burial"
                    INNER JOIN "names_name"
                        ON ( "burials_burial"."name_id" = "names_name"."id" )
                    INNER JOIN "cemeteries_grave"
                        ON ( "burials_burial"."grave_id" =
                            "cemeteries_grave"."id")
                    WHERE (
                        LOWER("names_name"."first_name") IN ('william', 'david', 'smith')
                        AND LOWER("names_name"."middle_name") IN ('william', 'david', 'smith')
                    )
IN: print names2.raw_query

OUT: SELECT "burials_burial"."id", "burials_burial"."name_id",
                    "burials_burial"."grave_id",
                    "burials_burial"."interment_date",
                    "burials_burial"."user_id",
                    "cemeteries_grave"."search1_id" AS "cemetery_id",
                    '1' AS "rank"
                FROM "burials_burial"
                INNER JOIN "names_name"
                    ON ( "burials_burial"."name_id" = "names_name"."id" )
                INNER JOIN "cemeteries_grave"
                    ON ( "burials_burial"."grave_id" =
                        "cemeteries_grave"."id")
                WHERE (
                    (LOWER("names_name"."first_name") SIMILAR TO '%(william|david|smith)%')
                    OR (LOWER("names_name"."middle_name") SIMILAR TO '%(william|david|smith)%')
                    OR (LOWER("names_name"."last_name") SIMILAR TO '%(william|david|smith)%')
                )
```

I have also used the cursor directly with the query and get results set back, although not as objects so this is not ideal. But it does show that python/django can handle the query:

```
IN: from django.db import connections
IN: cursor = connection.cursor()
IN: cursor.execute(names2.raw_query)
IN: results = cursor.fetchall()
IN: len(results)

OUT: 1
```

So, again, my question. Why does a seemingly valid query give me the 'tuple' object has no attribute 'id' error?

Comment: Is it a typo, or you don't have your `names2` defined? `names1 = Burial.objects(...); names1 = Burial.objects(...)`

Comment: Good catch. That is just a typo. I will edit.

Comment: Please note, the typo is just in the text here. It is not in the code. Problem still persists.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Your code is hard to reproduce. Please, add your models.py and upload some test data (it is better to submit it via pastebin) to load to the database.

Comment: I did try to debug it yes. I used ipdb as well as PyCharm where I walked through the code with everything. In fact, there doesn't seem to be any difference between the two query sets. I'll try and post the models as well as some test data a little later.

Comment: Ok, per sobolevn's suggestion, I have pasted the models that this uses, as well as some initial data. If you use the exact queries that I have above each query should return one result. http://pastebin.com/Bw2fx7NM

Comment: thank you, i will try to help you soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that I have a % sign in the SQL. PostgreSQL's Similar To is a cross of LIKE and POSIX regex. It uses the % as a wildcard, and will require a wildcard just as the LIKE statement will. I find that when I remove the %, I don't get the error described, but I also don't get the actual results I am looking for.

Python uses % for string formatting as outlined here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting. According to another stack overflow post the way to overcome this is to use %%.

There are therefore two work arounds. First is to use PostgreSQL's ~ operator, which does POSIX regex only. This lets me take out the % wildcard. The resulting query is this:

```
query6 = """
                    SELECT "burials_burial"."id", "burials_burial"."name_id",
                        "burials_burial"."grave_id",
                        "burials_burial"."interment_date",
                        "burials_burial"."user_id",
                        "cemeteries_grave"."search1_id" AS "cemetery_id",
                        '1' AS "rank"
                    FROM "burials_burial"
                    INNER JOIN "names_name"
                        ON ( "burials_burial"."name_id" = "names_name"."id" )
                    INNER JOIN "cemeteries_grave"
                        ON ( "burials_burial"."grave_id" =
                            "cemeteries_grave"."id")
                    WHERE (
                        (LOWER("names_name"."first_name") ~ {0!s})
                        OR (LOWER("names_name"."middle_name") ~ {0!s})
                        OR (LOWER("names_name"."last_name") ~ {0!s})
                    )
                """

names6 = Burial.objects.raw(query6.format(terms.replace('\'', '')\
                                    .replace(', ', '|')\
                                    .replace('(', '\'(')\
                                    .replace(')', ')\'')))
```

The other is to have the replace input with two % characters, bypassing the string replacement like so:

```
names2 = Burial.objects.raw(query2.format(terms.replace('\'', '').replace(', ', '|').replace('(', '\'%%(').replace(')', ')%%\'')))
```

Thanks so much for the comments and time put in on this.

Comment: You can accept your own answer, if you want to. I did not manage to solve this.